# Estimate a matrix of numbers based on known corner values?

Tags: python, r, matrix, multidimensional-array

There's probably a name for the algorithm I want, but I'm not sure how to find
it. I have lots of 96-well plates like this:

```
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
   ------------------------------------
A | X  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  X |
B | O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O |
C | O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O |
D | O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O |
E | O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O |
F | O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O |
G | O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O |
H | X  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  X |
   ------------------------------------
```

I've measured the light level at each corner with a light meter, and would like
to use those four values (marked with `X`s) to estimate the levels everywhere
else. I think I want some kind of weighted average based on how close a well is to
each corner.

The levels tend to vary diagonally if that matters. For example the top
right will be highest, bottom left lowest, and the other two somewhere
inbetween (but possibly nowhere near average).

My gotos are usually R and python but any language is OK since I just need to write the matrixes as CSV files.

Comment: I think you would need to generate some sort of Gaussian distribution, having each X point as the center of it, but I honestly don't know how.

Comment: Do you want a linear interpolation between the values? Are you trying to work out the gradient of the background?

Comment: a bilinear interpolation will do the trick. This can help: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14798/bicubic-bilinear-interpolation-in-r

Comment: Thanks guys, that looks like what I wanted! I'll see if I can work it out from that question and post the code.

Comment: Or not, beaten to it already.

Comment: This answer should work as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113019/how-can-i-create-a-surface-plot-with-missing-values-in-r/30113368#30113368

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not that advanced but may help:

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

c1 = 0  # Corner values
c2 = 1
c3 = 1
c4 = 4

a=np.linspace(c1, c2, 8)
b=np.linspace(c3, c4, 8)
c = np.array([np.linspace(i,j,12) for i,j in zip(a,b)])

print np.shape(c)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(c)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Joe's is really nice but "not that advanced" is more what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

And if you'd like to do the same in R using the default bilinear (or other interpolation method of your choosing):

```
library(raster)

##  Four corner values defined as a matrix, raster:
m <- matrix(c(12,4,3,9), 2, 2)
r <- raster(m)

##  Construct a new raster, with dimentions matching
##    the grid you're interpolating to:
r_i <- raster(nrows=200, ncols=200, ext=extent(r))

##  Resample your four corners, the default is using
##    bilinear interpolation:
r_i <- resample(r, r_i)

##  Plot our results:
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(r, zlim=c(-10,25))
plot(r_i, zlim=c(-10,25))
```

[image]

Note that bilinear interpolation may not be your best option since your corner values are known and you'd likely want those values to remain unchanged in your interpolated data.  A more sophisticated technique could be employed (splines, geostatistical, etc.) if desired.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for 2D interpolation.  There are a number of different interpolation methods you could use.

As a quick python example (I'm sure R has plenty of options, as well):

```
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y, x = np.mgrid[:12, :12]

xcorners = x[0,0], x[0, -1], x[-1, 0], x[-1, -1]
ycorners = y[0,0], y[0, -1], y[-1, 0], y[-1, -1]
zcorners = [1, 2, 3, 4]

xy = np.column_stack([xcorners, ycorners])
xyi = np.column_stack([x.ravel(), y.ravel()])
zi = scipy.interpolate.griddata(xy, zcorners, xyi)
zi = zi.reshape(x.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
grid = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, zi)
ax.scatter(xcorners, ycorners, c=zcorners, s=200)
fig.colorbar(grid)
ax.margins(0.05)

plt.show()
```

[image]