# Substituting missing values based on both row and column averages

Tags: r

As far as I know, missing data (NA's) in a data frame can be substituted by either row- or column-based averages. But what I'm trying to do in R (but not sure if it's possible) is calculating averages for missing cells that is based on both rows and columns where the cell with missing value is located. I was wondering if you had any suggestions.

Here is the sample data with NA's:

```
nr <- 50
mm <- t(matrix(sample(0:4, nr * 15, replace = TRUE), nr))
mm[,c(4,7,12,13)]<-NA
mm[c(3,5,8,9,10,13),]<-NA
```

Comment: Would be great if you could give a reproducible example and explain what is your expected output.

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113019/how-can-i-create-a-surface-plot-with-missing-values-in-r/30113368#30113368

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the OP wanted to replace the `NA` element based on the row/column averages of that index, we get the row/column index using `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE` ('ind'). Get the `colMeans` and `rowMeans` of the dataset ('df') subsetted by the columns of 'ind', and replace the `NA` elements by the average of the corresponding elements of  'c1' and 'r1'.

```
ind <- which(is.na(df), arr.ind=TRUE)
c1 <- colMeans(df[,ind[,2]], na.rm=TRUE)
r1 <- rowMeans(df[ind[,1],], na.rm=TRUE)
df[ind] <- colMeans(rbind(c1, r1))
```

---

Or as @thelatemail suggested we can use `outer` to get the combinations of `colMeans` and `rowMeans` and then replace the NA values based on that.

```
ind <- is.na(df)
df[ind] <- (outer(rowMeans(df,na.rm=TRUE), colMeans(df,na.rm=TRUE), `+`)/2)[ind]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix( sample(c(NA, 0:5), 10*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=10))
```

Comment: No need for the `which` etc... `ind <- is.na(df)` will be sufficient. As will: `df[ind] <- (outer(rowMeans(df,na.rm=TRUE), colMeans(df,na.rm=TRUE), \`+\`)/2)[ind]` using the same concept.

Comment: @thelatemail It works.  Looks like a different approach.  Are you not interested in posting that as a separate solution?

Comment: I don't know if it is worth a new answer. It is essentially the same `mean(row+col)` approach as you suggested, just changing the assignment slightly.

Comment: The above solution works, however in the columns where all values are Na's the averages are not calculated, and instead the cells are labeled as `NaN`. Is there a way to modify the above code to just rely on row averages in such cases, instead of writing NaN's?

Comment: @akrun Currently I use this code which only accounts for rows `k <- which(is.na(df), arr.ind=TRUE); df[k] <- rowMeans(df, na.rm=TRUE)[k[,1]]` , would love to include columns in the "averaging" process but without getting columns consisting solely of NaN's

Comment: @Oposum I am not sure I understand your comment correctly.  Can you update your post with a small reproducible example and expected output.  In that way, it become more clear.

Comment: @Oposum Thanks for the example.  Can you also update with the expected output based on the input.  My solution is replacing the NAs with row/column averages.

Comment: @akrun I can't figure out how to substitute NA's with expected outputs, but I agree with your solution. With the exception that in the columns that consist completely of NA's, the NA's don't get substituted with a number, but with NaN's and that's what I am trying to avoid

Comment: @Oposum If you get `NaN` for row/columns that are completely NA, what do you want to replace that with?

Comment: @akrun in that case, if no numbers in the column, then just row averages

Comment: @Oposum I think you need `colMeans(rbind(c1, r1), na.rm=TRUE)`  Suppose if both column and row means are NaN, then it will return `NaN` as there is no other way.